# Flask-Rebar Rule Validation

Tags: python, rest, flask

I need to validate a `Flask` rule in a REST API that is built using `Flask-Rebar`. I've tried the following method:

```
@registry.handles(
    rule='/horses/<int:horse_id>',
    method='GET',
    marshal_schema=GetHorseByIdSchema()
)
def getHorseById(horse_id):
    return {"horse_id": horse_id}
```

This is using the `<int:my_var>` syntax as specified [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_variable_rules.htm). When entering an integer value as the `horse_id` everything works correctly. The issue comes from entering a non-integer value, i.e. `a`; this throws a `404 Not Found` status code when I was expecting a `400 Bad Request`.

I don't think I can use any of the marshalling schemas for this so I'm unsure as to what to try next, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

This is how Flask/Werkzeug behaves, so its a bit beyond Flask-Rebar's control. That is, the following will also return a 404 for `/horses/a`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/horses/<int:horse_id>')
def getHorseById(horse_id):
    return str(horse_id)
```

With that, here are some workarounds:

**(1) Custom URL converter: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.url_map**

This would look something like:

```
import flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class StrictIntegerConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            flask.abort(400)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['strict_integer'] = StrictIntegerConverter


@registry.handles(
    rule='/horses/<strict_integer:horse_id>',
    method='GET',
    marshal_schema=GetHorseByIdSchema()
)
def getHorseById(horse_id):
    return {'horse_id': horse_id}
```

However, routing is done outside of application context, so we can't use flask.jsonify nor Flask-Rebar's errors to raise nice JSON errors.

**(2) Check the type inside the handler function**

```
from flask_rebar.errors import BadRequest

@registry.handles(
    rule='/horses/<horse_id>',
    method='GET',
    marshal_schema=GetHorseByIdSchema()
)
def getHorseById(horse_id):
    try:
        horse_id = int(horse_id)
    except ValueError:
        raise BadRequest('horse_id must be an integer')
    return {'horse_id': horse_id}
```

This is a little less elegant, but it works.
The Swagger document will default to a string type for the horse_id parameter, but we  can work around that as well:

```
from werkzeug.routing import UnicodeConverter

class StrDocumentedAsIntConverter(UnicodeConverter):
    pass

app.url_map.converters['str_documented_as_int'] = StrDocumentedAsIntConverter
registry.swagger_generator.register_flask_converter_to_swagger_type('str_documented_as_int', 'int')

@registry.handles(rule='/horses/<str_documented_as_int:horse_id>')
...
```

**(3) Accept Flask/Werkzeug behavior**

Depending on how badly you need 400 instead of 404, it might be most practical to do nothing and just give in to how Flask/Werkzeug do it.